# Should shell scripts work in absolute or relative paths?

Tags: shell-script

I am in the process of converting some batch scripts into shell scripts. The batch scripts have cd commands but still use absolute paths.

foo.bat:

```
pushd
cd C:\some\directory
copy C:\some\directory\foo.txt C:\some\other\directory
popd
```

I believe the cd in this script is redundant as the file being copied is being called using absolute paths. I need to convert this to a shell script. I have the following two options:

test1.sh:

```
cp /some/directory/foo.txt /some/other/directory
```

test2.sh:

```
cd /some/directory
cp foo.txt /some/other/directory
```

This first one uses only cp with absolute paths and the second one uses cd and relative paths.

My question is: Which one of these two examples is the better practice in terms of using paths in shell scripts?

As a side question, is pushd/popd needed in either of these examples?

Comment: Relative paths with `cd` unchecked for errors (what happens if the `cd` fails?) can be problematical.

Comment: `cd '/some/path' || exit 1`

Comment: Erm, what Unix or Linux system uses drive letters and \ as a path seperator?

Comment: Your second example is still using an absolute path. It should have been `cp foo.txt ../../some/other/directory` to only use relative paths.

Comment: @symcbean fixed

Comment: @jlliagre the second path in the second example is actually going to be another machine, so i left it as a "relative path" in this example. My question is specifically referring to how to call the file to be copied, in this case foo.txt

Comment: Whether the file is local or not doesn't matter, there are absolute paths, the ones that start with a `/`, all other ones are relative paths. Your second path is absolute but I understand your question isn't related to that second argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I experienced, it depends mostly on your needs and preferences
You will find a lot of documents in which this is left to the user. This is what i noticed:

- absolute paths are clearer: who will have to maintain/modify your script (you or others) will be able to know every time what directories are involved;
- with absolute paths you are sure the involved directories are the one with the exact path you are writing in the script;
- relative paths are shorter, but you need to be sure of the subtree you're working into;
- you can achieve shortness replacing recurring paths with a variable at the beginning of the script (e.g. /var/log/app/component/module/logfile.log -> $module_log_dir/logfile.log)

As thrig noticed, you could add a check for the involved directories just before the command to execute.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't necessarily a bad thing to call `cd` in a script, but this should be done sparingly. Multiple calls to `cd` are a “code smell”. Absolute paths are generally preferable.

`cd` can fail. Be sure to handle errors properly.

After a call to `cd`, relative paths become invalid. In particular, if you're writing a wrapper script that prepares some stuff and then runs another command, never call `cd`: the user might rely on the command being run in the original directory. If your script uses file names passed on the command line, they're normally relative to the original directory; you can prepend `"$PWD/"` to them to make them absolute but that leads to poor error messages if something goes wrong.

The variable `PWD` always contains the current directory, so you can save it into another variable and change back by calling `cd` later. However, beware that this can fail in some edge cases, such as a script running with low privileges that isn't allowed to change back into its original directory, or a directory that gets moved while the script is running.

Beware of relative paths: they can begin with `-`, and command arguments beginning with `-` are interpreted as options if you don't take precautions. Absolute paths don't have this problem.